# In Inkscape, how can I rotate a 2D object on the Z axis so that it appears 3D?

Tags: inkscape, vector, 3d

I have an image of a road that I have drawn as if I were a drone, looking down on it from above.

I would like to now add perspective to it, which would be easy if I were able to take the containing box, treat it like a plane, and slowly rotate it back into the Z axis...flattening the image such that the farther edge is smaller (receding) than the nearest one.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I envisioned something that would just stretch it at the bottom edge and pinch it at the top, so that the containing square became a quadrilateral with the top edge smaller...is that doable?

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: If screen axes are x and y then rotating around z would make it rotated along screen. Surely you want to rotate around y or x axis.... Anyway do you need perspective or is isometric enough

Comment: Are you meaning an [extrusion](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/ExtrudeTool) or a [perspective](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Extensions-ModifyPath.html#Extensions-Perspective) effect? Can you post a sample image and tell us something about your efforts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously you want this:

[image]

In the left there's some black shapes drawn as seen straight to downwards when flying above the shapes. The shapes are paths and path-like basic curves such as circles and rectangles. Raster images do not work nor groups, but paths and path-like curves which do not overlap (see NOTE1) can be combined with Path > Combine.

In the right path effect Perspective Envelope is added and the corners are dragged with the node tool to the wanted perspective.

The shapes can be made free and editable without losing the perspective by applying Path > Object to Path and Path > Break apart.

Path effect can be copied and pasted to another path. Simply copy an effected path to the clipboard, select another path and apply Path > paste path Effect.

NOTE1: Actually also overlapping paths can be combined, but if there's fill colors, they can get unified, vanish or there can appear to be holes. Everything can be fixed after the enveloping by applying Path > Object to Path and Path > Break Apart. An example:

[image]

There's an ellipse and a blue rectangle. Fill color vanished with Path > Combine. The coloring was taken from the ellipse. After inserting Perspective envelope and making the parts free again all colors were re-inserted manually.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do.  I had tried the "Perspective" option without success but may have been doing it with a flawed quadrilateral.  It suddenly started working and was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the clear visuals to go along.